# Print functions in API is not showing in ECS logs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-ecs

I have given many `print` functions to check line by line of code in my API and it is deployed in ECS cluster. The logs are not showing the `print`functions of my API. Is there any way to see the logs like terminal.